# Lengthy boolean search of strings in python

Tags: python, full-text-search, boolean

I'm trying to search a set of strings for a specific set of words, and perform some actions if the various boolean conditions are met. I currently have an approach that works, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way than what I have.

```
strings = ['30 brown bears', '30 brown foxes', '20 green turtles', 
            '10 brown dogs']

for text in strings:
    if ('brown' in text) and ('bear' not in text) and ('dog' not in text):
        print text
```

This works as desired and prints `30 brown foxes`. What concerns me, however, is adding in more terms to the search. For example, what if 'cat', 'mouse', 'rabbit', etc. are all added to the `if-statement`? This seems to be a clunky and non-Pythonic way to approach things, so I'm hoping someone has a different way for this to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this is the best way, but one thing you could do is use `all` in combination with two other control objects - one that contains the items you want to include (`brown`, in this case), and other that includes those you want to ignore:

```
In [1]: strings = ['30 brown bears', '30 brown foxes', '20 green turtles', '10 brown dogs']

In [2]: keep = ('brown')

In [3]: ignore = ('bear', 'dog')

In [4]: for text in strings:
   ...:     if all([k in text for k in keep] + [i not in text for i in ignore]):
   ...:         print text
   ...:         
   ...:         
30 brown foxes
```

Comment: We had similar ideas, but I like yours better.

Comment: I liked both ideas very much, but I'm going to go ahead and accept this one, but I do very much like both answers and will likely play around with both. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: @user1074057 No problem at all, happy it helped!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> strings = ['30 brown bears', '30 brown foxes', '20 green turtles', '10 brown dogs']
>>> conditions = [('brown', True), ('bear', False), ('dog', False)]
>>> for text in strings:
    if all((x in text) == c for x,c in conditions):
        print text

30 brown foxes
```